# Subview vertical align middle in view with auto layout constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, subview

I need to locate a subview vertical align middle in a view without hardcode the top value 150 using constraint programmatically. I wish to achieve something like below:

[image]

Below is my code so far, Please advise.

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
 var viewInner:UIView = UIView()
    var viewOuter:UIView = UIView()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewInner.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        viewOuter.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        viewOuter.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 400, 400)

        viewInner.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        let viewsDictionary = ["viewInner":viewInner]

        viewOuter.addSubview(viewInner)
        self.view.addSubview(viewOuter)

        //Add Constraint

        var constOuterH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[viewInner(>=200)]-10-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        var constOuterV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-150-[viewInner(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

        viewOuter.addConstraints(constOuterH)
        viewOuter.addConstraints(constOuterV)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want it to be centered but always have the top have a fixed offset, don't you really just want a fixed top and bottom value and not truly center alignment?

Comment: i wish to have viewInner always 100px in height and viewOuter height can change to any value. Fix top is not neccessary.

Comment: viewInner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewOuter.frame.size.width - 20, 100);
viewInner.center = CGPointMake(200, 200); And remove constOuterH and constOuterV.

Comment: If the center is always fixed, what would cause the size of this view to change at all?

Comment: @Acey seems like kaneyip wants to animate outer view height but keep innerView always centered to outer view. Perhaps he's trying to create a login form ? :)

Comment: @kaneyip Have added a demo app to my answer, see if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the non-visual formatting way of adding constraints:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSlayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewOuter attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relateBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY .......]];
```

to center align things.

The above type of "relational constraints" (it's what I personally call them) is what I tend to use for specifying relations between two views e.g. center alignment, relative positioning.

Visual Formatting language on the other hand is more useful for pinning views to each other from my own observation.

Here's a demo app:

### ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *outerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *innerView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *outerViewHeightConstraint;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self initViews];
    [self initConstraints];


    // change height of outerView after 3 seconds
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self changeHeight];

    });
}

-(void)changeHeight
{
    self.outerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 150;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.innerView layoutIfNeeded];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

-(void)initViews
{
    self.outerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.outerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

    self.innerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.innerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.outerView addSubview:self.innerView];

    [self.view addSubview:self.outerView];
}

-(void)initConstraints
{
    self.outerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.innerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    id views = @{
                 @"outerView": self.outerView,
                 @"innerView": self.innerView
                 };

    // outer view constraints
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[outerView(300)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.outerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.outerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    // give outerView a default height e.g. 300
    // note we can animate the height of outerview later using this var
    self.outerViewHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.outerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:300.0];

    [self.view addConstraint:self.outerViewHeightConstraint];



    // inner view constraints
    [self.outerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[innerView]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.outerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[innerView(50)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.outerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.innerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.outerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    [self.outerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.innerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.outerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
}
```

After running the app for 3 seconds, you'll see the outer view (purple view) shrink in height while the red inner view remains centered within the purple view and maintains its height.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

You can also rotate the view too.

[image: screenshot 3]

Comment: One question, `self.innerView.NSLayoutAttributeCenterY = self.outerView.NSLayoutAttributeCenterY + 0`, now, outerView's center should be like 240 in 320*480 screen, if that is true, innerView's Y is also 240 in its superView, self.outerView?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean sorry but I'll say try taking my above code and changing the constraint for outerView such that outerView's top is equal to self.view's top (so outerView starts right at the top instead of being centered to self.view). See if innerView remains centered within outerView.